# How to Save an Image with its origin encoding

Tags: c#, .net, image, tiff, image-formats

I am facing an unexpected behavior when `loading and saving images` in `.net` by only using methods of the built in `System.Drawing` namespace.

**The way i do:**
I have got an Image which i'm loading by calling `System.Drawing.Image.FromStream()`.
After some operations i have to save the Image with the `Tagged Image File Format (TIFF)` - I achive this by using the built in `.net` way like this:

```
private void doSomethingAndSave(System.Drawing.Image image, string destFile)
{
  //...doin something...

  //..save the image as Tiff
  image.Save(destFile, ImageFormat.Tiff);
}
```

**This works as expected** - if I investigate the file by reading the `first 4Bytes` i get:

> 0x49 0x49 0x2a 0x20

Which successfully identifies a `TIFF-Image`. So far, so good...

**The Problem I'm facing:**
Later in my code I have to reload those images and maybe some from another source, where I dont can expect that they are encoded as `TIFF`, but i can ensure they are always created via `.net System.Drawing.Image.Save()`.
So no 3rd party programs/encodings are used.
I may have to perform some operations and save the image back to disk.
At this point i want to save the image in `their same origin format`.

For instance i'm perfoming the following operation:

```
public void RotateImage(string file)
{
   using(var img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(file))
   {
     img.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
     img.Save(file);
   }
}
```

But now if I investigate the file I can see that the format has been converted to PNG, the first 8Bytes are now:

> 0x89 0x50 0x4E 0x47 0x0D 0x0A 0x1A 0x0A

So the `Tiff`-Image got *"converted"* to a `PNG` file.
I can not provide the imageFormat `ImageFormat.Tiff` parameter by default, because maybe the origin file `is not a TIFF` encoded one - i have to keep the origin format!

I have tried to apply the source ImageFormat manually: (Which also ends up in a PNG file)

```
public void RotateImage(string file)
{
  using(var img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(file))
  {
    var imageFormat = img.RawFormat;
    img.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone);
    img.Save(file, imageFormat);
  }
}
```

Maybe because the `RawFormat` does not exist in the `ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders()`...
I came up to this because:
Another approach was to evaluate the encoding and apply on saving:

```
 public void PerfomOperation(string fileName)
 {
   using (var img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(fileName))
   {
     Imaging.EncoderValue format = imaging.EncoderValue.CompressionLZW;
     var codecInfo = this.GetImageCodecInfo(img);
     Imaging.Encoder enc = Imaging.Encoder.Compression;
     Imaging.EncoderParameters ep = new Imaging.EncoderParameters(1);
     ep.Param[0] = new Imaging.EncoderParameter(enc, (long)format);

     img.Save(fileName, codecInfo, ep);
   }
 }

public ImageCodecInfo GetImageCodecInfo(System.Drawing.Image image)
{
  var imgguid = image.RawFormat.Guid;
  foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders())
  {
       if (codec.FormatID == imgguid)
           return codec;
  }
  return null;  // "image/unknown";
}
```

But the `Guid` `{b96b3caa-0728-11d3-9d7b-0000f81ef32e}` in my `Image.RawFormat` **does not exist** in the `ImageCodecInfo` - although i used the default `.net` method `Save(image, ImageFormat.Tiff);` before!
So i thought the right codec must exist on my machine...?

**So finally:**
**How to Save a image with the origin imageformat**
*(System provided .net formats only are fine)*

Comment: It seems that GDI+ changes the image format on calling `RotateFlip`. Can you confirm that? What happens if you just load an image and then save it without any processing?

Comment: @dymanoid Hi - thanks - i also thought this - thats why read & store the RawFormat before rotating... But this happens also without Roating the image (just load & save) - You r right - as far as i know - rotate redraws the image... UPDATE: without roating & redrawing i get a GDI+ exception... i hat to look furhter into this..

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6944270/2846483): this GUID is a `MemoryBMP`. So my assumption was correct: GDI+ changes the internal format of the image on processing.

Comment: @dymanoid so you think just loading is changeing the Format? - because the format (guid) is the one of the MemoryBitmap BEFORE rotating the image... And as you see in my example i'm reading the property before rotating!

Comment: On my machine, the image format stays `TIFF` after just loading. Only manipulating the image changes its format. Maybe it depends on the source image or on the system configuration. I haven't investigated it deeper.

Comment: @dymanoid:  The  .Net format doesn't "change" the format. The image save logic simply ignores it. The default save format is _always_ PNG.

Comment: @Cadburry: You'll just need to do more byte detections like the one you do for TIFF, to identify other formats so you can re-save as them. It's that simple.